# Issues using vue-js-modal component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, modal-dialog, vue-component, es6-modules

I followed directions on how to use the component from their documentation however I get `TypeError: show is not a function`

In my main JS file (app.js) I added the following and adding to my project using npm

```
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'
Vue.use(VModal)
```

The documentation states that I can now call a modal from anywhere in the app, so I created a page specific JS file and included the following to hide/show a modal with `name="hello-world"` on the page that included vue, app.js and the page specific profile.js file.

```
export default {
    methods: {
        show() {
            this.$modal.show('hello-world');
        },
        hide() {
            this.$modal.hide('hello-world');
        }
    }
}
```

When I load the page, I don't see the modal content, however when I click the link `<a href="#" @click.prevent="show">Modal</a>` I get an error about the show method `TypeError: show is not a function`

I am using laravel mix and verified that everything is being compiled as expected.  Below is a how I am including JS files on the profile page:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/assets/js/manifest.js?ver=5.2.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/assets/js/vendor.js?ver=5.2.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/assets/js/app.js?ver=1569678574'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/assets/js/profile.js?ver=1569678574'></script>
```

I am trying to "level up" my Vue and JavaScript experience, previously I just stuck to writing ES5 and my Vue was written without components and bound to a page specific Vue instance, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

app.js

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

require('./global/header.js');

Vue.component('tabs', require('./components/Tabs.vue'));
Vue.component('tab', require('./components/Tab.vue'));

import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'

Vue.use(VModal)


new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

profile.js

```
export default {
    methods: {
        show() {
            this.$modal.show('hello-world');
        },
        hide() {
            this.$modal.hide('hello-world');
        }
    }
}
```

webpack.mix.js that compiles profile.js

```
mix
  .js("resources/js/pages/home.js", "assets/js/home.js")
  .js("resources/js/pages/teams.js", "assets/js/teams.js")
  .js('resources/js/pages/profile.js', 'assets/js/profile.js')
```

Comment: Are you using the default frontend scaffolding from Laravel?

Comment: Also, can you show your full Vue code, rather than just the `methods` object?

Comment: @vince I'm using Mix on a WordPress project.  I have edited original post to include app.js and profile.js

Comment: @vince I have a mix command that compiles page specific JS such as profile.js

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I suspect that the problem has to do with the way you are compiling your scripts... Based on the error you are getting, when your `show` function runs, `this.$modal` is defined, but `this.$modal.show` is either undefined, or is a property rather than a function. What do you get if you change your `show` function to this: `show() { console.log('$modal', this.$modal); }`?

Answer (score 2):

The error doesn't specify if its the $modal.show() function or your profile.js show() function that is undefined. I suspect that it's your profile.js show() function because it looks like everything is in order with regards to vue-js-modal.

You need to add profile.js as a vue mixin (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) in order for its functions to be added to the vue instance. So in your app.js add:

```
import profile from '/assets/js/profile'
Vue.mixin(profile);
```